# What is the Best Way to Dynamically Create an MSMQ Listener?

Tags: msmq

I was using Spring.NET to create a message listener at application startup.  I now need the ability to create 0-n listeners, some of which could be listening to different queues.  I will need to be able to create/destroy them at run-time.  What would be the best way to go about doing this?  My previous spring configuration was something like:

```
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">

  <object id='inputQueue' type='Spring.Messaging.Support.MessageQueueFactoryObject, Spring.Messaging'>
    <property name='Path' value='.\Private$\inputQueue'/>
  </object>

  <!-- MSMQ Transaction Manager -->
  <object id="messageQueueTransactionManager" type="Spring.Messaging.Core.MessageQueueTransactionManager, Spring.Messaging"/>

  <!-- Message Listener Container that uses MSMQ transactional for receives -->
  <object id="transactionalMessageListenerContainer" type="Spring.Messaging.Listener.TransactionalMessageListenerContainer, Spring.Messaging">
    <property name="MessageQueueObjectName" value="inputQueue"/>
    <property name="PlatformTransactionManager" ref="messageQueueTransactionManager"/>
    <property name="MaxConcurrentListeners" value="10"/>
    <property name="MessageListener" ref="messageListenerAdapter"/>
  </object>

  <!-- Adapter to call a PONO as a messaging callback -->
  <object id="messageListenerAdapter" type="Spring.Messaging.Listener.MessageListenerAdapter, Spring.Messaging">
    <property name="HandlerObject" ref="messageListener"/>
  </object>

  <!-- The PONO class that you write -->
  <object id="messageListener" type="Com.MyCompany.Listener, Com.MyCompany">
    <property name="Container" ref="transactionalMessageListenerContainer"/>
  </object>   

</objects>
```

Should I just programmatically do what this file is doing each time I need a new listener?  Should I not use Spring.NET's messaging framework for this?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm using Spring.NET judiciously (i.e. messaging, ADO.NET helpers, etc.) as you already stated, I would do it programmatically.  And then add the new graph to my existing container.  This way Spring.NET still manages lifecycle for me.